# An element access expression should take an argument.ts(1011)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using react. I got some errors

**1.**

```
const  [viewImages, setViewImages]  =  React.useState<{src: string, alt: string}[]>([]);
```

> error: An element access expression should take an argument.ts(1011)

[image]

**2.**

```
const onFileInputChange  =  ( e: Object ): void => {
        if (  e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0 )  {
            
setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        }
```

> error: Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)

[image]

I searched for this everywhere but doesn't found anything that could solve my errors can anyone
please help me.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to write Typescript in a Javascript file.

Comment: pls share reproducable example in ts playground